# Как передать пустую текстовую строку, вместе с текстом отправляемого сообщения, чтоб потом менять её содержимое через базу данных

Tags: java, android, строки, firebase, firebase-database

Есть приложение , которое позволяет оставлять сообщение пользователям, построенное на Firebase.

Пользователь просто пишет сообщение, и затем отправляет его. Сообщение записывается в базе данных и потом оттуда же при просмотре списка считывается.

В ListView мы создаем список сообщений, на основе которого можно видеть все отправленные сообщения, столбцом вниз.

Мне нужно реализовать так, чтобы вместе с сообщением передавалась пустая строка в базу данных, чтоб потом далее её изменять на своё значение (для того, чтобы получить вид сообщения типа "вопрос-ответ").

Например сейчас список с сообщениями выглядит так:

```
Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.01.2017 в 8:40
"Текст Сообщения"

Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.02.2017 в 8:50
"Текст сообщения"

Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.03.2017 в 8:55
"Текст сообщения"
```

Где и что добавить нужно в код, чтобы получилось при просмотре:

```
Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.01.2017 в 8:40
"Текст Сообщения"
"здесь пустое значение, которое я меняю в базе данных, дописав ответ на сообщение"

Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.02.2017 в 8:50
"Текст сообщения"
"здесь пустое значение, которое я меняю в базе данных, дописав ответ на сообщение"

Сообщение от пользователя:
Дата: 23.03.2017 в 8:55
"Текст сообщения"
"здесь пустое значение, которое я меняю в базе данных, дописав ответ на сообщение"
```

Строка передается вместе с содержанием text; 
Как реализовать отдельной строкой в базе данных ?

Comment: @Антон а вы наверное по какому то туториолу делали? можно ссылочкой поделиться?) Так раз так тоже сейчас буду рассматривать данный функционал в приложении.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй проверять существует ли строка ответа в базе. Если нет оставляй поле незаполненным. 
[Документация Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists)

Comment: мне нужно передать пустую строку, вместе с сообщением пользователя. например используется String text; мне нужно создать String myStrokaDlyaOtveta; и отправлять её при отправке основного текста сообщения пользователем. Получилось сделать как хотел, но неудобно редактировать в базе потом. нужная строка почему то уходит вместе с отправляемым текстом в базу.. Чтоб отредактировать, нужно открыть в базе именно строку текста сообщения, и там уже дописывать.

Comment: в Firebase зайдя в базу данных, я наблюдаю таблицу Messages, а в ней строку text: "сообщение_пользователя + "моя_строка" ", 

вместо нужного мне:   text:"сообщение_пользователя", моя_строка:"пустое_значение"

Comment: в общем всё идёт в одну строку с text; вместо нужной мне отдельной второй строки.